# Can every diffeomorphism be rescaled into a volume preserving one?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, conformal-geometry

This is a [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3577369/is-every-diffeomorphism-conformally-equivalent-to-a-volume-preserving-diffeomorp). Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be the **closed** unit disk, and let $f:D \to D$ be a diffeomorphism.

> Does there exist a smooth $h \in C^{\infty}(D)$ such that $h\cdot f$ is an **area-preserving** diffeomophism of $D$?

(*Clarification:* by $h\cdot f$ I mean multiplication of a scalar by a vector, i.e. $\big( h\cdot f\big) (x):=h(x)\cdot f(x)$).

Clearly, such an $h$ must send the entire boundary $\partial D$ either to $1$ or to $-1$. Another necessary condition is $\det\big(d (h\cdot f)\big) = 1$. Since

$$
d (h\cdot f)=h df+dh \otimes f=h df+f \cdot (\nabla h)^T,
$$

the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) implies that 
$$
1=\det\big(d (h\cdot f)\big)=h^2\det(df)+(\nabla h)^T \operatorname{adj}( hdf ) f.  \tag{1}
$$

In fact, I am not even sure whether the PDE $(1)$ always has a solution for every diffeomorphism $f$. (that is even when omitting the requirement that $h\cdot f$ would be a diffeomorphism, or even a map from $D$ into $D$-when looking only at the PDE with no other restrictions on the result-does there always exist a solution?)

Comment: What is meant by $h\cdot f$? (I'd read it a priori as $h\circ f$, but then the question would be trivial taking $h=f^{-1}$). Where does "conformally" intervene in the question? If I were reading the title, I'd interpret it as whether for each $f$ there exists $h$ conformal such that $h\circ f\circ h^{-1}$ is area-preserving.

Comment: @YCor I meant for the standard (scalar) multiplication of a vector by a scalar.  Your are right that the title was a bit misleading. I have edited the question to address this, and also clarified what do I mean by $h \cdot f$. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Surely yes? Pull the volume form $\omega$ back through $f$. $f^\star \omega$ is another volume form. Then the question is, does there exist $h$ so $\omega=h (f^\star\omega)$ which presumably can be shown to be true. Moser's theorem?

Comment: @AlexArvanitakis Hi, I don't follow your reduction. Why is the question equivalent to finding a function $h$ such that $ \omega=h (f^\star\omega)$? According to my calculation, $(hf)^*\omega \neq h (f^\star\omega)$. I also don't see the connection to Moser's theorem. If you could elaborate that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible, then
$$\mathrm{area}\,f^{-1}(S)=\mathrm{area}\,S$$
for any sector $S\subset D$.
But this identity might fail --- so, not in general.